# has a diagonalizable matrix jordan normal form or not?

Tags: matrices

i would like to ask if a matrix that is diagonalizable then that means that i hasn't Jordan normal form .

if that's not the case then please tell me some ways to check if a matrix has jordan normal form or not.

Comment: The matrix is a Jordan normal form of itself, right?

Comment: Do you want to check if a particular matrix *is* in jordan normal form, or whether at can be *brought* into jordan normal form by a suitable coordinate system (i.e., a suitable basis)?

Answer (score 4):

If you're working over the complex numbers, every matrix has a Jordan normal form.  If a matrix is diagonalizable, then the diagonal matrix appearing in its diagonalization **is** its Jordan normal form.